# How to access data from ViewBag in vue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am a totally new to asp.net and C# so sorry in advance if the question seems trivial. I am trying to pass data from the AspView so that I can use that in my Vue components. If I understand it correctly I could pass Data from the controller to the view like the following:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Message="Hello"
   return View()
}
```

Then I would access that passed data in the view like this:

```
@ViewBag.Message
```

but how can I pass that data to a vue Component?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

make the data available in javascript.

for example

```
window.Message= "@ViewBag.Message";
```

and in Vue

```
Vue.prototype.Message= window.Message;
```

or directly

```
Vue.prototype.Message= "@ViewBag.Message";
```